# Statement 'backup log' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database

I want to use ASP.NET migrator to connect a backend (the backend used to work with local database, but now, there is no local database)to an Azure database, but I encounter this error!

[image]

How can I solve the error?

Thanks

Comment: More information, please. How are you doing this migration? What version of SQL Server is your database hosted on?

Comment: The information that I have is I use the migrator of ASP.NET Zero, the backend currently do not connect to any database, I use the migrator to connect it to a Azure database

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot posted, you didn't mention your SQL server version. Let me assume that you are trying to use SQL server 2017 version. In that specific version, some of the feature are deprecated and one of those is ***BACKUP LOG***.

The other alternative procedure is to migrate to the lower versions of the database. There is an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/90635/restore-backup-from-2017-to-sql-2014-sql.html) that confirms that, we cannot perform backup from lower version to higher version and viceversa is possible.

Check with the server version and provide more information regarding the version you are using.